# How to force an iAd not to load?

Tags: ios5, iad

I am trying to test an alternate ad provider for times when didFailToReceiveAdWithError is called.

In the iOS simulator I keep getting the test iAd, so I don't know what happens when an iAd fails to load.

```
2011-12-01 04:56:11.601 App Name -[theViewController bannerViewDidLoadAd:]
2011-12-01 04:57:12.582 App Name -[theViewController bannerViewDidLoadAd:]
2011-12-01 04:58:13.580 App Name -[theViewController bannerViewDidLoadAd:]
2011-12-01 04:59:14.578 App Name -[theViewController bannerViewDidLoadAd:]
2011-12-01 05:00:15.581 App Name -[theViewController bannerViewDidLoadAd:]
2011-12-01 05:01:16.572 App Name -[theViewController bannerViewDidLoadAd:]
2011-12-01 05:02:17.574 App Name -[theViewController bannerViewDidLoadAd:]
2011-12-01 05:03:18.573 App Name -[theViewController bannerViewDidLoadAd:]
2011-12-01 05:04:19.570 App Name -[theViewController bannerViewDidLoadAd:]
2011-12-01 05:05:20.566 App Name -[theViewController bannerViewDidLoadAd:]
2011-12-01 05:06:21.567 App Name -[theViewController bannerViewDidLoadAd:]
2011-12-01 05:07:22.565 App Name -[theViewController bannerViewDidLoadAd:]
2011-12-01 05:08:23.563 App Name -[theViewController bannerViewDidLoadAd:]
2011-12-01 05:09:24.562 App Name -[theViewController bannerViewDidLoadAd:]
2011-12-01 05:10:25.559 App Name -[theViewController bannerViewDidLoadAd:]
2011-12-01 05:11:26.558 App Name -[theViewController bannerViewDidLoadAd:]
2011-12-01 05:12:59.340 App Name -[theViewController bannerViewWillLoadAd:]
2011-12-01 05:12:59.770 App Name -[theViewController bannerViewDidLoadAd:]
```

Is there a way to force an iAd to fail to receive an ad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running debug builds, you should see occasional errors.  The [iAd Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/TestingiAdApplications/TestingiAdApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH6-SW1) says:

> While you are developing your application, iAd Network sends test
>   advertisements to your application. To assist you in validating your
>   implementation, the iAd Network occasionally returns errors to test
>   your error handling code. You can also test your error handling
>   support manually by turning your device’s wireless capability off.

I've definitely observed this behavior in my own apps.  Or, like it says above, turn wireless off.

Comment: I left it running for several hours, and while the debug log shows my code works, I didn't see it with my own eyes. But it will fail a couple of times an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Theres no literal way to stop the iad simulation from sending an ad. The way I would do this is to put a random number generator with the code that sets up your ads.  Have one value set up an iAd and another call the `didFailToLoad` method so your can test your new system.

Hope that helps

Comment: Is it possible to call `didFailToLoad`? If I have an `ADBannerView` called `bannerView` there is no such `[bannerView didFailToLoad];`